# Java 8 compute() and computeIfPresent() to check an existing value

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap

I have this piece of code :

```
if (notificationSend.get(key) != null && notificationSend.get(key).equals(value)) {
   return true;
} else {
   notificationSend.put(key, value);
   return false;
}
```

and I want to know if it is possible to refactor it using Jav8  Enhancements like `compute()` , `computeIfPresent()` or `computeIfAbsent()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `value` is non-null, you don't need to use a conditional, or any of those `compute*` methods.

```
ValueType oldValue = map.put(key, value);
return value.equals(oldValue);
```

Comment: This is not the same as OP's code. Here you're always putting the `(key, value)` entry in the map, no matter if it's already present or not.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner in what situation would that lead to different map contents? (I mean, other than with dodgy hashCode and equals implementations).

Comment: In a situation where objects have identity, which is to say: always. Maybe this is not important in OP's context, but I think it's worth a mention in your answer.